# Angular Ionic icon binding does not compile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a custom version of `<ion-select>` under which I use the standard `<ion-select-option>`.

```
<custom-select>
    <ion-select-option></ion-select-option>
</custom-select>
```

When I bind an icon like this

```
<ion-select-option value="test" icon="information-circle">
    Test
</ion-select-option>
```

The code compiles and the custom wrapper component takes care of adding the icon in the appropriate place.

But when I bind it like this

```
<ion-select-option value="test" [icon]="getIcon()">Test2</ion-select-option>
```

I get error **Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select-option'.**

I need the latter because adding the icon is conditional.

Example: [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-mbwe4m?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.page.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, using `attr.icon` works:

```
<ion-select-option
  value="test2"
  attr.icon="{{ 1===1 ? 'information-circle' : null }}"
>
  Test2
</ion-select-option>
```

I still don't know why it works although ion-select-option does not have icon attribute officially.

Answer (score 0):

`ion-select-option` don't have `icon` property, check the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option)

You can create your own select component and load into a [popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)

For example

component.html

```
...
<ion-list>
    <ion-item (click)="selectItem('test')">
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="logo-ionic"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Test</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
...
```

component.ts

```
...
constructor(public popoverController: PopoverController) {}

selectItem(val) {
    this.popoverController.dismiss(val);
}
...
```

home.ts

```
async presentPopover(e: Event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      event: e
    });

    await popover.present();

    const { role } = await popover.onDidDismiss();
    this.roleMsg = `Popover dismissed with role: ${role}`;
}
```

Comment: But why it still works and presents the icon?